# get the handle of a (real) monitor by its index

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, c++11

Suppose I have 3 monitors. How do I get the handle of the second one only by its index? EnumDisplayMonitors() won't work because it enumerates the pseudo-devices as well and EnumDisplayDevices() doesn't give me the handle.

Comment: What about `MonitorFromRect`, `MonitorFromPoint`, or `MonitorFromWindow`? Will any of them work for you? All of them return an `HMONITOR`.

Comment: unfortunately not, I need the index

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `EnumDisplayMonitors()` instead of `EnumDisplayDevices()` to access the `HMONITOR` handle of each monitor.

However, monitors are not identified by index.  `GetMonitorInfo()` can tell you which monitor is "primary", but that is all. There is no way to know which monitor is "second", "third", etc.  And you can't use monitor locations to determine that, either, as the "second" monitor could be positioned anywhere in relation to the "primary" monitor, and then the "third" monitor can be positioned anywhere in relation to either "first" or "second" monitor.

So you have to hope that `EnumDisplayMonitors()` enumerates in the order that the monitors are installed, then you can do something like this:

```
struct sEnumInfo
{
    int iIndex;
    HMONITOR hMonitor;
};

BOOL CALLBACK GetMonitorByIndex(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{
    sEnumInfo *info = (sEnumInfo*) dwData;
    if (--info->iIndex < 0)
    {
        info->hMonitor = hMonitor;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

```
sEnumInfo info;
info.iIndex = 1;
info.hMonitor = NULL;

EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, GetMonitorByIndex, (LPARAM)&info);
if (info.hMonitor != NULL)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can enumerate devices with `EnumDisplayMonitors()` and check if it is pseudo monitor with `EnumDisplayDevices()`

While you iterating through display monitors using `GetMonitorInfo()` you can get `MONITORINFOEX` with a name of a monitor's device.

Then using `EnumDisplayDevices()` you can get `DISPLAY_DEVICE` which contains `StateFlags` with info if current monitor is a pseudo monitor (or as in case bellow attached to desktop)

```
BOOL DispayEnumeratorProc(_In_ HMONITOR hMonitor, _In_ HDC hdcMonitor, _In_ LPRECT lprcMonitor, _In_ LPARAM dwData)
{
    TClass* self = (TClass*)dwData;
    if (self == nullptr)
        return FALSE;

    MONITORINFOEX monitorInfo;
    ::ZeroMemory(&monitorInfo, sizeof(monitorInfo));
    monitorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(monitorInfo);

    BOOL res = ::GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &monitorInfo);
    if (res == FALSE)
        return TRUE;

    DISPLAY_DEVICE displayDevice;
    ::ZeroMemory(&displayDevice, sizeof(displayDevice));
    displayDevice.cb = sizeof(displayDevice);

    res = ::EnumDisplayDevices(monitorInfo.szDevice, 0, &displayDevice, 0);
    if (res == FALSE)
        return TRUE;

    if (displayDevice.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP)
        self->RegisterDisplay(monitorInfo);

    return TRUE;
}

void TClass::EnumerateDisplayMonitors()
{
    BOOL res = ::EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, &DispayEnumeratorProc, (LPARAM)this);
    if (res == FALSE)
        Print("Failed");
}
```

Also you can sort your monitors by iterating through `EnumDisplayDevices()`

If you pass `NULL` as first parameter to `EnumDisplayDevices()` it will return adapter's info based on second parameter. In this case your devices will have determined order.

You can compare `DeviceName` from `DISPLAY_DEVICE` with `szDevice` from `MONITORINFOEX` that you stored before to sort your `HMONITORs`

```
void TClass::SortDisplayMonitors()
{
    DISPLAY_DEVICE displayDevice;
    ::ZeroMemory(&displayDevice, sizeof(displayDevice));
    displayDevice.cb = sizeof(displayDevice);

    std::map<std::string, DWORD> devices;
    for (DWORD iDevNum = 0; ::EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, iDevNum, &displayDevice, 0) != FALSE; ++iDevNum)
        devices.insert({displayDevice.DeviceName, iDevNum});

    auto compare = [&devices](MONITORINFOEX& l, MONITORINFOEX& r)
        {
            DWORD il = -1;
            DWORD ir = -1;

            auto foundL = devices.lower_bound(l.szDevice);
            if (foundL != devices.end())
                il = foundL->second;

            auto foundR = devices.lower_bound(r.szDevice);
            if (foundR != devices.end())
                ir = foundR->second;

            return (il < ir);
        };

    std::sort(m_monitors.begin(), m_monitors.end(), compare);
}
```

PS: You can write
DWORD il = std::numeric_limits< DWORD >::max();
insted of
DWORD il = -1;
but don't forget to define NOMINMAX before you include Windows.h

Comment: I think you should add an explanation as to why you did what you did.

Answer (score 2):

you can exclude primary monitor, here is sample code (styles may vary) :

if [DEVMODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-_devicemodea) dmPosition x == 0 and y == 0, then it is primary monitor.

> For display devices only, a POINTL structure that indicates the
>   positional coordinates of the display device in reference to the
>   desktop area. The primary display device is always located at
>   coordinates (0,0).

check x, y to define second or third.

```
  LONG second_x=0;
  LONG second_y=0;

  DWORD deviceNum = 0;
  DISPLAY_DEVICE displayDevice;
  DEVMODE devMode;

  memset(&displayDevice, 0, sizeof(displayDevice));
  displayDevice.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
  while(EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, deviceNum, &displayDevice, 0))
  {
    EnumDisplaySettings(displayDevice.DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &devMode);
    if (devMode.dmPosition.x == 0 && devMode.dmPosition.y == 0)
    {
      // primary monitor
    }
    else
    {
      // second or third monitor
      second_x = devMode.dmPosition.x;
      second_y = devMode.dmPosition.y;
    }
    ++deviceNum;
  }

  m_pMainWnd->SetWindowPos(NULL,(int)second_x,(int)second_y,0,0,SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOSIZE);
```