# Get monitor index from its handle (HMONITOR)

Tags: c++, windows, multiple-monitors

I'm interested in getting the monitor index (1-based, to match Windows numbering) given the monitor handle.

Case of use: given a window's rect I want to know the monitor it belongs to. I can get the handle of the monitor using [`MonitorFromRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromrect):

```
// RECT rect
const HMONITOR hMonitor = MonitorFromRect(rect, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
```

How can I get the monitor index from this handle?

PS: not sure if duplicate, but I've been looking around with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29412926/get-the-handle-of-a-real-monitor-by-its-index) with the opposite question: finding the handle given the index (0-based in that case).

Based on it I worked this solution:

```
struct sEnumInfo {
  int iIndex = 0;
  HMONITOR hMonitor = NULL;
};

BOOL CALLBACK GetMonitorByHandle(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{
  auto info = (sEnumInfo*)dwData;
  if (info->hMonitor == hMonitor) return FALSE;
  ++info->iIndex;
  return TRUE;
}

int GetMonitorIndex(HMONITOR hMonitor)
{
  sEnumInfo info;
  info.hMonitor = hMonitor;

  if (EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, GetMonitorByHandle, (LPARAM)&info)) return -1;
  return info.iIndex + 1; // 1-based index
}
```

Comment: I upvoted but after testing more carefully I don't think that really works: the index isn't the same as what you see in the Windows Display Settings, but more like assigned depending on the monitor position (1 being the most on the left it seems).