# Retrieve windows placement from saved workspace in Windows Registry

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, registry

I have a MFC application that automatically saves and restores its workspace (window position, open panes, sizes, etc) to Windows Registry (e.g. `HKCU\Software\foo\bar\Workspace`). It's working correctly.

Now I'm interested in showing a splash screen *before* loading any other window (user requirements). This splash screen must be shown in the same screen where the application's main window will be shown.

I've noticed that in the Registry there is a value `HKCU\Software\foo\bar\Workspace\WindowPlacement\MainWindowRect` that I guess contains the information about the top-left point and size of the window. With that information I'm able to get the correct screen number (see [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54326893/1485885) if interested in how).

How can I get and interpret that `MainWindowRect` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I've been able to see, the `MainWindowRect` happens to be the direct memory dump of a `RECT` structure. A simple cast is enough to get the window's rect.

Here the full code snippet for getting the value as well as the associated monitor:

```
// Assumes SetRegistryKey has been already called
if (const auto hKey = AfxGetApp()->GetSectionKey("Workspace\\WindowPlacement")) {
  DWORD dwReturn[32];
  DWORD dwBufSize = sizeof(dwReturn);
  if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "MainWindowRect", 0, 0, (LPBYTE)dwReturn, &dwBufSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    const auto rectWindow = *(RECT*)dwReturn;

    // Get monitor index from window's rect
    const auto hMonitor = MonitorFromRect(&rectWindow, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
    const auto iMonitorIndex = GetMonitorIndex(hMonitor); // see linked post for GetMonitorIndex implementation
  }
  RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```